# android external class call on mainactivity

Tags: android

manifest

```
    <activity android:name=".util.SSIDCheck">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>  <receiver android:name=".util.SSIDChangeReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="intent.action.TEST"></action>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>

    </receiver>
```

mainActivity

```
enter code here// setContentView(R.layout.activity_blackeye_main);
    SSIDCheck ssidCheck = new SSIDCheck();
    ssidCheck.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

I want show display SSIDCheck 
what should I do?

mainActivity what command code?

Answer (score 0):

In Manifest File

```
<activity  android:name=".MainActivity">
   <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In mainActivity class

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SSIDCheck ssidCheck = new SSIDCheck();`write your code here`
}
```

Comment: this way ssidCheck is never used :)